# Hide other div element

Tags: jquery

I have some code:

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="items">item1</div>
      <div class="items">item2</div>
      <div class="items">item3</div>
      <div class="items">item4</div>
  </div>
```

How I can click one of items. Then only **this** items is visible. Other items are hide?

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? That's pretty trivial. Thousands of sources to look at by just searching on Google (or here).

Comment: Please post some code and elaborate your question, read [ask]

Comment: sorry because of it. I want to find it quickly. I will care it next time.Thanks for idea!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/siblings

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks. Thought my questions is quite trivial. I think siblings is totally reasonable

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution could be:

```
var items = $('.items');
items.on('click', function () {
   items.hide();
   $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to include all div with a class and exclude the current div.

Code:

```
 $(".items").click(function () {
     $(".items").not(this).hide();
 })
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/BWUje/

Comment: I've up voted this one. Shorter and efficient.

Comment: you don't need to wrap `this` into a jQuery object - you can just do `$(".items").not(this)`

Answer (score 2):

**in HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="items">item1</div>
      <div class="items">item2</div>
      <div class="items">item3</div>
      <div class="items">item4</div>
  </div>
```

**in JS**

```
$(".items").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".item").hide();
    $(this).show();
}):
```

reference [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".items").on("click", function () {
        // Hide all
        $(".items").hide();
        // Show clicked
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```